# Heap & Stack Java

Tags: java

Я знаю, что ссылки на объекты создаются в памяти стека а сами объекты в куче. В коде ниже я пытаюсь переполнить кучу создавая большое количество объектов Main(), используя зацикленность в конструкторе, и вместо outOfMemoryError получаю stackOverflow.

```
public class Main {
    public Main() {
        new Main();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Почему? Как мне переполнить кучу?

Comment: Стек намного меньше кучи.

Comment: сделайте так, чтобы один объект съедал 100мб

Comment: Вот, например OutOfMemoryError https://ideone.com/XjmuMf

Comment: @Кирилл а чем я в моем случае так переполняет стек?

Comment: рекурсия порождает на стеке адреса возврата

Comment: почитайте что такое рекурсия и как она работает

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На каждый вызов функции в памяти выделяется кусок стека. В нём хранятся адрес возврата в вызывающую функцию, локальные ссылки, примитивные переменные и, возможно, другая служебная информация. При выходе из функции стек очищается. Но из-за рекурсии вы не выходите из функции, пока не перестанете вызывать функцию саму из себя. Соответственно, размер стека стремительно растёт и возникает его переполнение.

Чтобы добиться ошибки `OutOfMemoryError`, объекты должны занимать в памяти слишком много места. Обычно эта ошибка возникает либо из-за выделения слишком большого куска памяти (например, [огромный массив](https://ideone.com/lDCZdN))

```
static int[] arr = new int[1000000000];
```

либо из-за [утечек памяти](https://habr.com/ru/post/132500/).

Как правило, размер стека намного меньше размера кучи. Если размер стека обычно измеряют мегабайтами или десятками мегабайт, то размер кучи может достигать сотен мегабайт или нескольких гигабайт. Именно поэтому, у вас программа падает с ошибкой `StackOverflowError`.